# sql count consecutive zeros

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
date         N
---------------
2016-06-22  0.0 
2016-06-23  0.0 
2016-06-24  0.0 
2016-06-25  0.0 
2016-06-26  14.0    
2016-06-27  0.0 
2016-06-28  0.0 
2016-06-29  3.0
```

and I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the cumsum of the consecutive zeros in column `N` and resetting whenever there is a non-zero value. This is the kind of output I'm looking for.

```
date         N    cum0 
----------------------
2016-06-22  0.0     1
2016-06-23  0.0     2
2016-06-24  0.0     3
2016-06-25  0.0     4
2016-06-26  14.0    0
2016-06-27  0.0     1 
2016-06-28  0.0     2
2016-06-29  3.0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define each group by the number of non-zero numbers before it.  Then use `row_number()`:

```
select date, n,
       (row_number() over (partition by grp order by date) -
        (grp <> 0)::int
       ) as cum0
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where n <> 0.0) over (order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/5864) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: for some reasons it's not working with sqlite or postgresql

Comment: Your question is tagged "postgres", so this solution is not for SQLite.  The code basically works.  I made a small change -- which was just an off-by-1 error, but this solution is correct.